# Prestashop 1.7 ps_categoryproducts is not translatable

Tags: prestashop-1.7

The prestashop module categoryproducts shows no strings to translate. There are two strings in the template that can be translated:

```
{l s='%s other product in the same category:' sprintf=[$products|@count] d='Modules.Categoryproducts.Shop'}
{l s='%s other products in the same category:' sprintf=[$products|@count] d='Modules.Categoryproducts.Shop'}
```

I can't find any of this two strings in the module translations, following any of this two paths:

```
Translations->Installed modules translations

Modules->Modules and Services->Installed modules->Products in the same category->Configure->Translate
```

In both cases, prestashop shows no strings to translate.

I'm using prestashop 1.7.0.4, I just updated it because there was a bugfix on this release related to module translations, but there was no luck.

I've tried modifying the template, and changing the 'd=' parameter to other values.

PS: Someone is having the same problem: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/578520-module-translation-prestashop-17/ there is no solution in this thread (yet) but the cause seems to have been located.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update about module translations on the http://build.prestashop.com/ website. PrestaShop team post updates about modules and other technical stuff here.

You can check following URL for more details on module translations:

http://build.prestashop.com/news/new-translation-system-prestashop-17/#as-a-module-contributor

Check the update on 'Update - January 2017' to be specific.